# Masquerading from a custom routing table does not work

Tags: iptables, nat, iproute2, masquerade

In Ubuntu 22.04 server, masquerading/NATing from a custom routing table does not work (for VPN clients).
It does work however when I do not route traffic to a custom table (and let it remain in the main table).

Default policy for FORWARD chain is set to ACCEPT.

**Edit:**
Current configuration:

```bash
#  sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

#  iptables -t filter -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

#  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
#  iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

The VPN subnet is 10.250.51.0/24.

```bash
#  ip rule add from 10.250.51.0/24 lookup table main
#  ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32754:  from 10.250.51.0/24 lookup main
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

It works fine.
But when I change to below:

```bash
#  ip rule del 10.250.51.0/24 lookup table main
#  ip rule add from 10.250.51.0/24 lookup table 1000
#  ip route add default via eth0 table 1000
#  ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32761:  from 10.250.51.0/24 lookup 1000
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

#  ip route show table 1000
default dev eth0 scope link
```

it does not work.

Comment: You should probably add more detail, including current configuration.

Comment: I would guess that your VPN clients do not (need to) route and thus will never reach chain POSTROUTING.